# TrimEnd or TrimStart method in C# that accepts a string?

Tags: c#, string

Does C# have a `TrimEnd` or `TrimStart` method that has a `string` parameter? 
No, even if we used `string.ToCharArray()` like `TrimEnd(str.ToCharArray());` it doesn't behave well.

For example:

```
string sam = "Sammy";
sam = TrimEndOrStart(sam, "my", true);
```

`sam` should equal `"Sam"`

Comment: "it doesn't behave well" -- It does behave well; it behaves as documented. If what you want is something else, it would be useful to first specify what you want, and then look for a function that does that.

Comment: Ok, it would trim all the characters in the array but regardless of the sequence.

Comment: Indeed, that's what it's meant for, so that it can be called as `s.TrimEnd(' ', '\t')`, and any trailing spaces or tabs get removed regardless of number or order. That's not what you want. What's not clear, though, is what exactly you do want. For example, do you want `MyTrimEnd("Sammymy", "my")` to return `"Sam"`, or `"Sammy"`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use StartWith / EndWith like:

```
static class StringTrimExtension {
    public static string TrimStart(this string value, string toTrim) {
        if (value.StartsWith(toTrim)) {
            int startIndex = toTrim.Length;
            return value.Substring(startIndex);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static string TrimEnd(this string value, string toTrim) {
        if (value.EndsWith(toTrim)) {
            int startIndex = toTrim.Length;
            return value.Substring(0, value.Length - startIndex);
        }
        return value;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
        string s = "Sammy";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        string trimEnd = s.TrimEnd("my");
        string trimStart = s.TrimStart("Sa");
        Console.WriteLine(trimEnd);
        Console.WriteLine(trimStart);
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you have a need for ignoreCase you can implement and overwrite for your trim methods and use the overwrites from the [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)/[EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.endswith%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) methods.

**EDIT:**
With recursion:

```
static class StringTrimExtension {
    public static string TrimStartRecursive(this string value, string toTrim) {
        string result = value;
        while (TrimStart(result, toTrim, out result)) {}
        return result;
    }

    public static string TrimEndRecursive(this string value, string toTrim) {
        string result = value;
        while (TrimEnd(result, toTrim, out result)) { }
        return result;
    }

    public static string TrimStart(this string value, string toTrim) {
        string result;
        TrimStart(value, toTrim, out result);
        return result;
    }

    public static string TrimEnd(this string value, string toTrim) {
        string result;
        TrimEnd(value, toTrim, out result);
        return result;
    }

    public static bool TrimStart(this string value, string toTrim, out string result) {
        result = value;
        if (value.StartsWith(toTrim)) {
            int startIndex = toTrim.Length;
            result= value.Substring(startIndex);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool TrimEnd(this string value, string toTrim, out string result) {
        result = value;
        if (value.EndsWith(toTrim)) {
            int startIndex = toTrim.Length;
            result = value.Substring(0, value.Length - startIndex);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string s = "Sammymymymy";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        string trimEnd = s.TrimEndRecursive("my");
        string trimStart = s.TrimStartRecursive("Sa");
        Console.WriteLine(trimEnd);
        Console.WriteLine(trimStart);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Those ones cannot do a recursive trim.

Comment: Recursions should be **[avoided for various reasons](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html)** (overhead of stack usage => possibility of a **[stack overflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx)**) unless you have no other choice - use **[a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690462/trimend-or-trimstart-method-in-c-sharp-that-accepts-a-string/44633997#44633997)** instead.

Comment: I agree and thank you for your comment, but this is just a sample :) in productive code there should also be some argument checks and stuff, but I think we are on the same page :)

Answer (score -3):

```
/// <summary>
/// Does a nice trim for your string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Subject">The subject</param>
/// <param name="Search">What to trim on the string</param>
/// <param name="TrimEnd">If set to true we trim the end</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string TrimEndOrStart(string Subject, string Search, bool TrimEnd)
{
    if (TrimEnd)
    {
        if (Subject.EndsWith(Search) == false)
        {
            return Subject;
        }

        Subject = ReverseString(Subject);

        Start:
            string[] Array1 = Subject.Split(new string[] { ReverseString(Search) }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (Array1.Length == 1)
        {
            if (Subject.Equals(Array1[0], StringComparison.Ordinal) == false)
            {
                Subject = Array1[0];
                goto Start;
            }
        }

        Subject = StaticMethods.ReverseString(Subject);
        return Subject;
    }

    if (Subject.StartsWith(Search) == false)
    {
        return Subject;
    }

    Start2:
        string[] Array2 = Subject.Split(new string[] { Search }, 2,  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (Subject.Equals(Array2[0], StringComparison.Ordinal) == false)
    {
        Subject = Array2[0];
        goto Start2;
    }

    return Subject;
}


/// <summary>
/// Reverses a string array
/// </summary>
/// <param name="StrArray"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ReverseString(string Str)
{
    char[] ObjectArr = Str.ToCharArray();
    char[] NewObjectArr = new char[ObjectArr.Length];
    int counter = 0;

    for (int index = ObjectArr.Length - 1; index > -1; index--)
    {
        NewObjectArr[counter] = ObjectArr[index];
        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    Str = "";
    StringBuilder StrBu = new StringBuilder(1000);

    for (int index = 0; index < NewObjectArr.Length; index++)
    {
        StrBu.Append(NewObjectArr[index]);
    }

    Str = StrBu.ToString();
    return Str;
}
```